# Checking MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql, database

I understand that I cannot get a 100% correct answer, however I need to submit in half an hours time so I'm really just checking the syntax.

Below is my Query:

```
SELECT V.MAKE, COUNT(V.MAKE) LIMIT 10
FROM VEHICLE V
JOIN ENGINE E
ON V.ENGINE_ID = E.ENGINE_ID
WHERE V.MANU_FROM <= 2005 AND V.MANU_TO >= 2006
AND E.PRICE >= 2000 AND E.PRICE <= 3999
ORDER BY COUNT(V.MAKE)
```

The query has to: Find top 10 makes with the most cras being produced between 2005 and 2006, with a price between 3000 and 3999

I'm just looking for any help spotting an obvious mistake

Comment: Do you get any error message ? And if you need 10 results, you should use LIMIT 10, not LIMIT 5 obviously...

Comment: I haven't got any software on my pc to test the query. And I changed it to 10! Thanks

Comment: Looks like a school work then...

Comment: Well I hardly see any professionnal situation when you're asked to write a query without a computer to run it. So this is probably a test question, so either you're a student either you're applying for a job. If I'm not mistaken in both case this isn't the kind of stuff we do on SO

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, simply test it and see will it fly. Also cheating on a test is bad.
Anywho obvious mistakes:

- not using between for your WHERE statements
  (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)
- LIMIT goes at the end (or almost) of your statement
- The amount in limit is plain wrong, should be 10.
- Minimal price is supposed to be 3000, not 2000.

That is enough help for a query, have fun doing the work!

Answer (score -1):

At first glance aren't your MANU_FROM and MANU_TO criteria incorrect? shouldn't it be

```
V.MANU_FROM >= 2005 and V.MANU_TO <= 2006
```

Comment: I think the original is right. If the make was manufactured from 2004 to 2008, then it was being produced in 2005 and 2006.

Comment: I guess my point is how can it be less than 2005 and greater than 2006 if it's supposed to be BETWEEN 2005 and 2006?

Comment: It's two DIFFERENT columns. One is when it started being manufactured, the other is when it stopped being manufactured. So if you want to know if it was being manufactured in any particular year, that means it started in or before that year and stopped in or after that year.

Comment: I kind of see it... I guess I put too much stock in the name of the columns (FROM and TO)... sorry :-/